# Powershell script to save only the free diskspace value (in GB) for C:\ in a variable

Tags: powershell

I need to write a power-shell script, where if the free disk space is more than 50GB, then -"do something", else exit the script - do nothing.

For that I am trying to save the free disk space value in a `$var` and play with an `if-else` in my script, something like:

```
$var = <parse disk space free from Get-PSDrive C output>
if ($var -ge 50) {
        #Do something
}
else {
        #Do nothing
}
```

I tried this so far:

`$var = Get-PSDrive C -psprovider Filesystem | select-object @{Name="Free"; Expression={$_.Free/1GB}}`

But printing the `$var` gives me: `@{Free=112.352230072021}`, but what I wanted is `112`, i.e just the free disk-space value , rounded off to anything before the decimal.

What needs to be done ? is there any `Unix` style `awk` or `sed` to parse outputs in power-shell ?

Comment: @Tomalak No its not. The primary question is how to deal with comparing `if disk-space > 50GB`.

Comment: ...yeah I deleted the comment, it was too snappy on second thought. But "how to round a number in PowerShell" definitely is in the core of your question, and you definitely could have figured this part out on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Free` property on a PSDrive is in Bytes. It's very much straightforward to take the drive(s) where it exceeds a certain number, no need to calculate anything, no need for variables, no need for `if`/`else`:

```
Get-PSDrive C -PSProvider FileSystem | where Free -gt 50GB | foreach {
    Write-Host $_
    # do something
}
```

`50GB` is a PowerShell built-in convenience shorthand for `50 * 1073741824`. Other such shorthands (`KB`, `MB`, `TB`, `PB`) exist.

Comment: I need to wrap it in a `if-else`, as rest of my working script is ready, and I will not need a `for-each` like construct.

Comment: @dig_123 `$var = Get-PSDrive C -PSProvider FileSystem | where Free -gt 50GB`

Comment: ...then `$var` will contain the drive, or be empty (i.e. `$null`). You can do `if ($var) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: But I don't see how a `foreach` would not fit with the rest of your script, it literally has no bearing or dependency whatsoever on any other code. Doing this with `if`/`else` is exactly the same but in more lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

if you REALLY want to use an `if/else` structure, then this would work. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$TargetDisk = 'c'
$MinDiskFree_GB = 50
# uncomment the line below to show the "too small" error msg
#$MinDiskFree_GB = 5000

$ActualDiskFree_GB = [math]::Round((Get-PSDrive -Name $TargetDisk).Free / 1gb, 2)

if ($ActualDiskFree_GB -gt $MinDiskFree_GB)
    {
    Write-Host ('Drive [ {0} ] has enuff free space. [ {1} GB]' -f $TargetDisk, $ActualDiskFree_GB)
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Warning ('    Drive [ {0} ] does not have enuff free space. [ {1} GB]' -f $TargetDisk, $ActualDiskFree_GB)
    }
```

output with each of the two test values ...

```
Drive [ c ] has enuff free space. [ 845.77 GB]
WARNING:     Drive [ c ] does not have enuff free space. [ 845.77 GB]
```

what it does ...

- defines the variables
  if you need to run this more than once, it would likely work better as a function with parameters.
- gets the free space in GB
- compares the actual versus the minimum desired free GB
- does the appropriate thing

Comment: `[math]::Round((Get-PSDrive -Name $TargetDisk).Free / 1gb, 2) -gt $MinDiskFree_GB` is a *very* complicated way of saying `(Get-PSDrive -Name $TargetDisk).Free -gt 50GB`.

Comment: @Tomalak - it was done that way to parameterize things in a way that makes it easy to convert the code into a function - AND to make what was happening both obvious and easy to change. ///// plus, it fits how i think about it ... [*grin*]

Comment: You can parameterize `(Get-PSDrive -Name $TargetDisk).Free -gt $MinDiskFree_GB * 1GB`.

Comment: ...but practically, it would be even better to avoid parameterizing in GB at all. `$disk.Free -gt $MinDiskFree` inside the function is enough. You can then call the function with `-MinDiskFree 50GB`, which reads more naturally than `-MinDiskFree_GB 50` and allows other limits (`1TB`) to be passed just as easily without having to change any of the implementation.

Comment: @Tomalak - the use of GB was to make it fit the OPs request ... and to re-emphasize the unit used in that particular situation. one expects that the final product would be designed to use the preferred target unit the coder chose to use. [*grin*] ///// please remember that one of the OPs problems seemed to be not knowing that the unit returned by the cmdlet was in _bytes_ while the unit used in the test limit was in _gigabytes_.

Comment: The OP wrote `@{Name="Free"; Expression={$_.Free/1GB}}`, they pretty well knew that the unit returned was bytes. Writing it as "`.Free -gt 50GB`" emphasizes the unit and uses GB to fit the OP's request, without being unnecessarily convoluted. \*shrug\*

Comment: @Tomalak - we obviously have _very_ different views of what makes sense here. [*grin*]